# What is the proper content type for one-word boolean REST resource?

Tags: rest, http, content-type

I'm building an API, and for the most part there will be JSON and HTML content there. But a few very specific endpoints only render `true` or `false`, and also accept `true` or `false` in POST. That is the entire body of the request or response.

What would be the correct content-type header for this resource?

I'm using `text/plain`. `application/text` also sounds ok, though it I haven't found it used anywhere else (is it?)

Comment: To answer questions like “is `application/text` a proper media type?”, use the [IANA media types registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml).

Comment: To anyone reading @VasiliyFaronov's comment and wondering whether that is, in fact, a proper media type: it's not :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The single words `true` or `false` are valid JSON, so you may use `application/json` with these values.

However, [it is recommended that your JSON messages be either an object or an array](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7493#section-4.1) as some software may not work properly if this is not the case.  To follow that recommendation you might instead return a value such as

```
{"result":true}
```

Comment: While I agree, I would also mention [RFC 7493 § 4.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7493#section-4.1).